# Clear value inside a text box in AngularJS without manipulating data in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form for password updation.
HTML :

```
<div class="profile-fields">

                <p>Please provide your profile details</p>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="username">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="UserName" ng-model="profile.name" ng-disabled="true" />
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" ng-model="profile.password" value="" validator="required" required-error-message="Password is required" valid-method="watch" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password">Retype Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password1" value="" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password1" validator="required" required-error-message="Password is required" valid-method="watch" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The new password is sent from the first password box using `ng-model="profile.password"`

Controller :

```
myApp.controller('profileController', ['$scope', 'userResolved', 'userServices', '$location', function ($scope, userResolved, userServices, $location) {

    $scope.oldPassword = userResolved.data.password;
    $scope.profile = userResolved.data;
$scope.cancelProfile = function () {


        $location.path("/dashboard");


    }
    $scope.updateProfile = function () {

        if ($scope.profileForm.$valid && $scope.profile.password == $scope.password1) {
            if ($scope.profile.password != $scope.oldPassword) {
                userServices.saveProfile($scope.profile).then(function (result) {
                    if (!result.error) {
                        alert("Profile updated!!! Please login again with new password.");
                        $location.path("/logout");
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (data) {
                    $scope.error = data.data;
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.error = "Password cannot be same as before!!"

            }

        }
        else {
            $scope.error = "Passwords mismatch!!"
        }
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that on page load the model is displaying the current password in the first password text box. User will have to manually clear the current password from the first textbox to enter the new one. I can't just clear the `profile.password` because I am using it for validation. Is there anyway we can clear the value inside the element on page load in a way that we are not manipulating ng-model?

The text box should not display the current password on page load. How can I achieve this?

Comment: but it displays just "dots" so what is wrong with that?

Comment: As a standard, you NEVER keep the password value in the variable after using it. Once you succeeded to log-in, you clear the password variable. Adhering to this will resolve your issue.

Comment: could you please put your code in `plnkr` ?

Comment: @rakaz : user will have to manually clear the textbox to enter the new value every time. Thats kind of inconvenient.

Comment: @FDavidov : Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @ Phoenix yep, it's true. So use another variable and copy it, or as @FDavidov says, do not keep it, ask user for password every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new var and assign that var the password, and then clear the model variable.

```
var myPassword = profile.password;

profile.password = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will Help you,

```
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="params.text"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="type something here...">
    <span ng-if="params.text"
          ng-click="clearText()"
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" 
          style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: all;"
          uib-tooltip="clear">
    </span>
```

[image]

And the script :

```
    $scope.clearText = function() {
       $scope.params.text = null;  }
```